# Typo in tag --- [sicilian-tajmanov]

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been looking through the tag wiki, and found a typo in a tag.

[sicilian-tajmanov] --- should be [sicilian-taimanov].

Comment: That's not a typo, but an alternative, anglicized, spelling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have edited the questions with a new, correct tag and moved the description as well. So it is now fixed, and the wrong tag shall auto-delete in a day.